# SQL Delayed Durability Single Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

We have a stored proc that logs steps in every SP and writes them to a Activity_Log_Table.

Example :

```
EXEC write_activity_log 'Start of xxx process'
```

The SP is called to log the start of a process in another SP.

The problem is that we use hundreds of SPs every minute and each SP may have many steps logged - thus we are writing vast amounts of data `Activity_Log_Table` causing resource issues.

I have read about Delayed Durability and its performance improvements and was wondering if I can use this for just the write to this table. I have seen I can simply Commit a transaction with Delayed Durability turned on.

Could I add a line in the SP that writes to the `Activity_Log_Table` to simply add Delayed Durability to these log writes

e.g.

```
BEGIN TRAN
Insert into Activity_Log_Table (columns)
Values (@log_steps)
COMMIT WITH (DELAYED_DURABILITY = ON)
```

Will this only affect everything written to this table - leaving everything else on the DB to not be affected? Can Delayed Durability really speed up performance? I know there are issues with data being lost if server crashes etc but this is not client data that is critical - its just for debugging if required

Comment: I would argue that much logging of multiple steps like this might be helpful in development but is just going to cause issues in production. Do you really need to audit multiple steps in every procedure in production? That just seems like total overkill to me. But there could be some business or even legal issue where this makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say that the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability) doesn't already say, except for the bleedingly obvious ("try it out"). It would hinge a lot on what the "resource issues" are. Delayed durability may or may not alleviate them -- the total amount of data written to either log or data files does not change, for instance, though the number of requests may.

Comment: An alternative approach to delayed durability may be to use a service broker queue.